# Is it possible to use @RolesAllowed with Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and Keycloak 4.0.0.FINAL?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

For me, it's possible to solve the roles with the application.properties file or the method below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

I want to use the permissions with the annotation of @RolesAllowed. It's more secure, since you can not forget any endpoint. For me this is a big problem in

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
@RolesAllowed("note-reader")
public ResponseEntity<?> getNotes(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(noteService.getNotes(page), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In the article https://rieckpil.de/howto-microprofile-jwt-authentication-with-keycloak-and-react/ they use it like this. But they don't use spring. Is there a way to solve it in this way or is the properties file the way to do it in spring?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: No, you should use spring method security.
Read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security